# Не запускается приложение после завершения установки обновления через Intent и FileProvider

Tags: java, android, activity

Возникла такая проблема. Добавил обновление приложения по воздуху.
Cкачивается нужный .apk и запускаю установщик приложений через FileProvider.

```
Intent intent;
Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(apkUri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Все отлично работает, приложение устанавливается.

[image: Скриншот установщика]

Но на Android 11,12 при нажатии кнопки OPEN приложение не открывается.
Ничего не происходит.

Но в Logcat сообщение о запуске активности есть.

> START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN
> cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]  flg=0x10000000
> pkg=com.example.myapp cmp=com.example.myapp/.MainActivity} from uid
> 10067

Так же затем в логкате появляется Exception от packageinstaller:

> ```
> Failed to note usage stop
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to stop usage for com.android.packageinstaller, not in use
> at com.android.server.usage.AppTimeLimitController.noteUsageStop(AppTimeLimitController.java:955)
> at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService.reportEvent(UsageStatsService.java:918)
> at com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService$H.handleMessage(UsageStatsService.java:1364)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
> ```

Причем, на Android 7, 8 все запускается и работает без проблем.

Тестировалось как на эмуляторах с Android 7,8,11,12. Так и на физических устройствах с Android 7 и 11.

UPD. Забыл добавить, что по иконке все запускается без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после запуска intent вызвать

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Ответ интересный, но не совсем понятно, как он способен решить проблему автора вопроса.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: @NowhereMan, возможно, у него при обновлении не вызвался onDestroy. Хотя система, вроде, сама закрывает приложение во время обновления. Я лишь предположил, что не так, но не уверен, что это поможет...